# Android Studio not excluding a transitive dependency and complains about class conflict

Tags: java, android, gradle

Hi I'm working on an Android app and I need to use a library called Semantics3. The issue I'm having is that the Semantics3 library depends on a few different libraries one of which is org.json but Android Studio automatically includes its own unique version of org.json which causes various issues. I've tried a few things to work around this and I'll describe them below.

First, I just imported the Semantics3 library. All the code compiles but when code from the library runs to make a service call the app crashes. This is due to a "NoSuchMethod" error because Semantics3 makes use of a constructor from a class in org.json which the AS version doesn't include.

To get around this I made my own jar file of the Semantics3 code and add in the dependencies it needs on my own in Gradle. The app still crashes, though not because it can't find the constructor. In this case the error is due to an exception from org.json, specifically "org.json.JSONException: Value com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject". I couldn't figure out why this error was popping up so I decided to try out the Semantics3 library outside of Android and just made a simple Maven project. In the Maven project I can make service calls just fine with no issue, but if I add the jar file and dependencies on my own, I get the same error as in AS.

So I figure there's something missing in the source code on Github that I used to make the jar or something but that's beyond me to figure out, so I'm back at trying to just import the library. My final and current attempt involves trying to explicitly import the version of org.json that Semantics3 needs along with the Semantics3 library in Gradle. But when I bring in the Sematnics3 library I try to exclude the transitive dependency Semantics3 introduces to org.json. I've included the Gradle file for this attempt below.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.semantics3/Sem3Java
    implementation('com.semantics3:Sem3Java:1.2.4'){
        exclude group:'org.json:json'
    }

    implementation 'org.json:json'
    constraints {
        implementation(group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722') {
            because 'Semantics3 requires version 20190722 of org.json, not the default AS version'
        }
    }
```

The issue is when I try to run the code with the above setup in Gradle I get an error saying there are duplicate class definitions contained in the Semantics3 library and org.json library. And yes there are certainly conflicts but I thought the exclude bit to the Semantics3 implementation would be enough to prevent that from happening. Did I make a mistake somewhere or am I misunderstanding or misusing the exclude? If it makes a difference it appears the Semantics3 library does hardcode the org.json library into its Jar file. I appreciate any help with this. Thank you.